# Вычислить сумму элементов массива, расположенных после минимального элемента

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста понять в чем ошибки?

Компилятор пишет :

> Ошибка    C2568   <<: не удается разрешить перегрузку функции,
>
> Ошибка    C2563   несоответствие в списке формальных параметров,
>
> Ошибка    C2679   бинарный ">>": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "const char [3]" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma hdrstop
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, i, a[10], sum = 0;
    cout << "Kol-vo elementov: ";
    cin >> "%d" >> &n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "a[%d]=", i<< endl;
        cin >> "%d" >> &a[i];
    }
    cout << a[i] << " ";
    int min = 0;
    int kol = 0, firstNeg, nextNeg;
    if (a[0] < 0) {
        kol++;
        firstNeg = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[min] > a[i]) 
            min = i;
        if ((a[i] < 0) && kol < 1) { 
            firstNeg = i; 
            kol++; i++; 
        }
        if ((a[i] < 0) && kol < 2) { 
            nextNeg = i; kol++; 
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = firstNeg + 1; i < nextNeg; i++)
        sum += a[i];

    cout << "Summa = " << sum << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `cin >>"%d">> &n;` Брр... Такой смеси французского с нижегородским я еще не видел... Просто `cin >> n;` И тут - `cout << "a[%d]=" << i<< endl;` - тоже. `cout << "a[" << i << "]= ";` (и без `endl`!)  `cin >>"%d">> &a[i];` - просто `cin >> a[i];`

Comment: cout << "a[" << i << "]= "; (и без endl!) -а почему без end;?

Comment: Чтобы вводить в той же строке. Иначе - некрасиво...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение за 1 проход без создания самого массива.

```
cin >> N;
int min_e;
cin >> min_e;
int sum = 0;
while (--N){
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    if (a <= min_e){
        sum = 0;
        min_e = a;
    } else 
        sum += a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Изменил `cin`, `cout` на `scanf()`, `printf()`
Но мне не нравится то, что вы не задаете начальные значения для `firstNeg`, `nextNeg`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma hdrstop
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, i, sum = 0;
    printf("Kol-vo elementov: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d]=", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    int min = 0;
    int kol = 0, firstNeg, nextNeg;
    if (a[0] < 0) {
        kol++;
        firstNeg = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[min] > a[i]) min = i;
        if ((a[i] < 0) && kol < 1) { firstNeg = i; kol++; i++; }
        if ((a[i] < 0) && kol < 2) { nextNeg = i; kol++; }
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = firstNeg + 1; i < nextNeg; i++)
        sum += a[i];

    printf("Summa = %d\n", sum);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Я бы реализовал это так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma hdrstop
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, i, sum = 0;
    printf("Kol-vo elementov: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d]=", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    int mn = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
        if(a[i] < a[mn]) mn = i;

    for(int i=mn+1; i < n; i++)
        sum += a[i];

    printf("\nSumma = %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вставлю и Свои 5 копеек. Вариант решения Вашей задачи на modern C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>


#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);

    std::array<int, 7> array{11, -1, 2, -1, 1, 2, 1};

    std::array<int, 7>::iterator min_element_iterator = std::min_element(std::begin(array), std::end(array));
    std::advance(min_element_iterator, 1);

    int sum_after_min = std::accumulate(min_element_iterator, std::end(array), 0);
    std::cout << "[Out] : Sum all element after min : " << sum_after_min << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Должен заметить, что алгоритм "min_element" вернет итератор на 1 вхождение в последовательности.